# admiral-global traffic policy

Tags: istio, azure-aks

```
apiVersion: admiral.io/v1alpha1
kind: GlobalTrafficPolicy
metadata:
  name: gtp-service1
  namespace: sample
  labels:
    identity: greeting
spec:
  policy:
    - dns: stage.greeting.global
      lbType: 1 #0 represents TOPOLOGY, 1 represents FAILOVER
      target:
        - region: us-west-2
          weight: 80
        - region: us-east-2
          weight: 20
```

above code taken from the GitHub, Can anyone help me to identify what my *- dns* will be ? or any reference document for admiral ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't specify host in the dns field. Just have "default"

And the GTP should work with your existing mesh endpoint.

To cross verify what's your host DNS check created ServiceEntry in your cluster.